# Finding the size of a view adjusted by a UIStackView swift

Tags: ios, swift, frame, uistackview

A number of views in a `UIStackView` are adjusted to fit the stack. The views are initialised with no frame because they are resized by the stack view. Is there a way which I can get the size of the views after they have been resized by the stack view?

Comment: This question needs some details to get better answers. 1. Why do you need to know a view's size when it's been resized by a stack view? 2. Where do you need to know when the view is resized? In other words, what code needs to handle the resize? Note that with the proper use of constraints it's very unlikely that you actually need to do anything here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sizes are available after `UIStackView.layoutSubviews()` finishes. You can subclass `UIStackView` and override `layoutSubviews`:

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("arrangedSubviews now have correct frames")
        // Post a notification...
        // Call a method on an outlet...
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not always true, unfortunately. I've encountered many cases where the geometry of the arranged subviews is **not** correct after `super.layoutSubviews()`. In my specific case, I always had to check them on the very next run loop, which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In your View's `layoutSubviews()`. 
However you need to force the UIStackView to layout first, using `stack.layoutIfNeeded()` before using its size.

eg:

```
public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Force the UIStackView to layout, in order to get the updated width.
        stack.layoutIfNeeded()

        let tabWidth = stack.arrangedSubviews[0].frame.size.width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to get a Stackview's subview frame is to use `convert`.

```
yourStackView.convert(viewInsideStackView.frame to: parentView)
```

This will return `viewInsideStackView`'s frame inside `parentView`'s coordinate system.

Comment: This doesn't get the subview's frame after getting adjusted by the stackview though.

Answer (score 0):

✅ Getting dimensions from UIStackview, helps me a lot.

```
let myStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [myView])
myView.setNeedsLayout()
myView.layoutIfNeeded()
print(myView.frame)
```